# Comment menu height invalid

Tags: bug, ios-app

After selecting a comment on [this post](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3938/176217), the comment menu height is invalid:

[image: Halfmenu]

When the comment is unselected then the word "ago" isn't visible:

[image: Unselected]

I think it happens when somebody edits a comment.

- App Version: 1.6.1.2
- Device: iPad Air 2 (Wi-Fi)
- OS Version: Version 10.0.2 (Build 14A456)