# Modification of comment being already notified

Tags: bug, ios-app

When you get notified about comment and saw it in the inbox section of the iOS app, then modification of this comment breaks inbox item height.

> [image: modified comment]

Refresh or switch to another tab don't help. Only restarting the app can help.

- App Version: 1.6.2.5
- Device: iPad Air 2 (Wi-Fi)
- OS Version: Version 10.2 (Build 14C92)

Comment: [Related question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/286350/339911)